# I use ethers.js deployment contract, but returned error: uncaught (in promise) error: unknown transaction override 0

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

I use ethers.js to deploy the contract, but returned an error: **uncaught (in promise) error: unknown transaction override 0**

at ContractFactory. getDeployTransaction (index.ts:1196:1)

at ContractFactory.< anonymous> (index.ts:1246:1)

at Generator. next ()

at fulfilled (index.ts:2:1)

Instead, the same contract can be successfully deployed with web3.js, except that the three parameters (contractname, contractsymbol, and contracturi) become garbled after deployment.

The code of using ethers.js deploy contract is as follows:

```
...
    window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    console.log("Account:", await signer.getAddress());
    
    const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory( bodyJSON2.abi, bodyJSON2.bytecode, signer );
    console.log("factory.signer:", factory.signer);
    await factory.deploy([contractName, contractSymbol, contractURI])
    .then(async function(contract){ 
      console.log("for debug. Contract Path: ", contract.address); 
    });
```

Contract code is as followed:

```
function initialize(string memory name, string memory symbol, string memory url
    ) public virtual initializer {
        __BXPP_init(name, symbol, url);
    }
    using CountersUpgradeable for CountersUpgradeable.Counter;
    CountersUpgradeable.Counter private _tokenIds;

    string private _baseTokenURI;

...
```

The relevant error codes in ethers.js are as follows:

```
getDeployTransaction(...args: Array<any>): TransactionRequest {
    let tx: TransactionRequest = { };

    // If we have 1 additional argument, we allow transaction overrides
    if (args.length === this.interface.deploy.inputs.length + 1 && typeof(args[args.length - 1]) === "object") {
        tx = shallowCopy(args.pop());
        for (const key in tx) {
            if (!allowedTransactionKeys[key]) {
                throw new Error("unknown transaction override " + key);
            }
        }
    }
```

The code of using web3.js deploy contract is as follows:

```
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    const BXPP = new web3.eth.Contract(bodyJSON2.abi);
    await BXPP.deploy({
      'data': bodyJSON2.bytecode,
      'arguments': [contractName, contractSymbol, contractURI]
    })         
    .send({
      'from': address,
      // gas: ,
      // gasPrice: '3000000'
    }, function(error, transactionHash){ console.log("error/transactionHash: ", error, transactionHash) })
    .on('error', function(error){ console.log("error: ", error) })
    .on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){ console.log("transactionHash: ", transactionHash) })
    .on('receipt', function(receipt){ console.log(receipt.contractAddress) 
    })
    .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ console.log("confirmationNumber:", confirmationNumber) })
    .then(async function(newContractInstance){
        console.log("for debug. ContractID: ", newContractInstance.options.address);                     
    });
```

I searched Google for almost a week, but I didn't find the answer. Does anyone have the same problem as me? Thanks!

Comment: I've just tried it. If don't take construction parameters, I deploy successfully. `await factory.deploy()
                .then(async function(contract){ `  My contract is upgradable. Is there any difference in parameter transfer for this upgradable contract?

Comment: The problem has been solved. There are two points:
1. Use ethers (the version in my machine) to deploy the contract, and pass the parameters without using arrays.
2. I used an initializable contract (initialized with initializer) and changed it to a normal contract (initialized with constructor).

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. There are two points:

1. Use ethers (the version in my machine) to deploy the contract, and pass the parameters without using arrays. Like this:

```
 await factory.deploy(contractName, contractSymbol, contractURI)
```

Not like this:

```
await factory.deploy([contractName, contractSymbol, contractURI])
```

2. I used an initializable contract (initialized with initializer) and changed it to a normal contract (initialized with constructor). Like this:

```
constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol, string memory url
    ) {
        __ContractTemplate_init(name, symbol, url);
    }
```

Not like this:

```
function initialize(string memory name, string memory symbol, string memory url
    ) public virtual initializer {
        __ContractTemplate_init(name, symbol, url);
    }
```